# Multiple Table Joins Help (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a school assignment and I've almost completed it but the last few questions have me stumped. We are using the AdventureWorks database - https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIHvD.jpg.

The troublesome question is as follows:

"List the American states/counties with the number of different phone number types for states/counties that have 500 or more of each phone number type.  Order by the count of each phone type desc"

I've never had to deal with this many tables before and it's got me stumped. Am I meant to join 7 or 8 tables together in order to link the Person.PhoneNumberType and Person.StateProvince tables together? How do I go about joining that many tables?

A nudge in the right direction is all I'm after.

Thank you

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  And `JOIN` again.

Comment: you use join query for that

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: In SSMS right click and select "Design Query in Editor ... "

Comment: @RegBes building queries with the query designer is never a good plan. Learn how to write queries yourself. It is not only faster to write but also faster to execute because the designer does not always write very good code.

Comment: @Sean, while the code may not be the greatest, for the novice it is the quickest way to get the basics of a query out and visually understand what the query is doing , this will get Liam what he needs in the shortest amount of time. he can see the result and build form there.

Comment: @RegBes the OP is trying to learn how to write queries for their school assignment. I would argue that it is worse for a novice than somebody experienced to use a code generating tool like the query designer.